# How read, find and replace .tif with jpg in XML file

Tags: python, pandas, xml, database

I hope you are doing well. I have the following XML files in folder.
I want to read all files from folder and read the file and change the file extension .tif with jpg in XML file.

as you can se below I have the following like where image is in .tif I want to convert end .tif with jpg
input:
000000000000.tif
output:
000000000000.jpg
Can anybody help me with this.
I have used Notepad++ for this
The xml file is not attaching so I can paste the input of .XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<annotation>
<filename>000000000002.tif</filename>
-<source>
<annotation>ESRI ArcGIS Pro</annotation>
</source>
-<size>
<width>128</width>
<height>128</height>
<depth>3</depth>
</size>
-<object>
<name>1</name>
-<bndbox>
<xmin>85.82</xmin>
<ymin>0.00</ymin>
<xmax>128.00</xmax>
<ymax>11.95</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>
-<object>
<name>1</name>
-<bndbox>
<xmin>42.56</xmin>
<ymin>0.00</ymin>
<xmax>85.88</xmax>
<ymax>6.05</ymax>
</bndbox>
</object>
</annotation>
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml_data = open('properties.xml', 'r').read()  # Read file
root = ET.XML(xml_data)  # Parse XML
```

Comment: Why not to use XSLT for the task?

Answer (score 0):

XML `Element`s have a `.text` attribute which can be read and set like a variable. You could accomplish your goal using some code like this:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("properties.xml")
filename_elem = root.find("filename")
filename_elem.text = filename_elem.text.replace(".tif", ".jpg")
```

Then you can output the file with the modified `filename` using `ElementTree`'s `.write()` method, like `root.write("properties_modified.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8", pretty_print=True)`, or overwrite the existing file by passing the original file name (`"properties.xml"`) as the first argument there.